# Can notify-send be used to send pop-up notifications to a Windows X server over ssh?

Tags: ssh, notification, xserver, notify-send

I'd like my backup script to issue a notification once it's done. I run Ubuntu as a headless server and login into it using PuTTY on Windows. I've already installed x11-apps and verified xclock and xcalc to run successfully on the Windows X server (Xming).

If this is not possible, which notification system can I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is 'truly' headless - as it will be when you installed a server edition of Ubuntu - then it will not have the X libraries installed and therefore will not be able to act as an X client, so there is no way for it to control the X server on Windows. (Note that not even `xterm` will be installed.)

If your PuTTY session is still open, then the server could use `wall` to make a notification appear on all terminals.

Otherwise, the customary (and resilient) way to notify the administrator is to send e-mail. If you use *cron* to trigger the backup job, you don't even need to do anything for that. I'm a bit out of touch with Windows, but I guess you can make Windows notify you when a specific email comes in.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually, I've installed x11-apps and am able to run xclock and xcalc successfully on the Windows X server (Xming). Given this, would it now be possible to use notify-send to issue a pop-up notification on my Windows PC?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice it will depend on the capabilities of the X server. Why don't you try it out?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this with [growl for windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/). Here's something that should get you started real quick:

- Install growl for windows
- On the 'security' tab of the growl configuration, disable the 'require password for LAN apps'(YMMV, I manage security using windows firewall) and enable 'Allow network notifications'

The above will enable a notification server on windows(add growl for windows to the startup applications so you always have it running)

There are many ways to send notifications from your ubuntu server, heres a simple way with python:
- Install python/virtualenv
- Install gntp package: `$ pip install gntp`

Now open a text editor and paste the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gntp.notifier


def send(description, applicationName='Sample Application', noteType="Message",
    title="Msg", applicationIcon=None, hostname='127.0.0.1',
    password=None, port=23053, sticky=False, priority=None,
    callback=None, notificationIcon=None, identifier=None):

    growl = gntp.notifier.GrowlNotifier(
        applicationName=applicationName,
        notifications=[noteType],
        defaultNotifications=[noteType],
        applicationIcon=applicationIcon,
        hostname=hostname,
        password=password,
        port=port,
        )

    result = growl.register()

    return growl.notify(
        noteType=noteType,
        title=title,
        description=description,
        icon=notificationIcon,
        sticky=sticky,
        priority=priority,
        callback=callback,
        identifier=identifier,
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    send('Testing sample application')
```

This assumes that your ssh client is forwarding port 23053 to your windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `notify-send` is not going to work from an ubuntu desktopless server. However `zenity` can do almost as good as `notify-send` with a little bit of scripting.

```
zenity --info --text="Notification body"
```

For example try

```
alias alrt='error_code=$?; __f(){ [[ $1 -eq 0 ]] && zenity --info --text 'Success' || zenity --error --text 'Error';  }; __f $error_code'
true; alrt
false; alrt
```

### Original alert behavior mimic

Original alert

```
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

Tweaked alert using zenity instead of notify-send

```
alias alert='zenity "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo --info || echo --error)" --text "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

Usage:

- `echo happy command; alert check this out`
- `echo sorrow command; false; alert check this out`